# how can i use frame in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, frame

This is my code but it doesn't work

if I run my code,It nothing to be display.
I think The problem is the src. or I need to change the layout .
Does somebody has experience...

```
<frameset rows="127,*,11" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame src="top" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" />
<frame src="center" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" />
<frame src="down" name="bottomFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="bottomFrame" />
```

Comment: run cakephp with frames is not a good idea. this code does not show anything or you have views with the name top / center / down. but you have to implement this views first.

Comment: I have the views with the name top / center /down.  also, I have implement the views of top ,center, down.  Also the controller. I still don't know where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't setup custom routing, you'll need to change the frame src to /controller_name/action ... In this case, /controller_name/top and so on.